# How do I get the slideshow to disappear after one cycle through (javascript)

Tags: javascript

this intro slideshow works so far, it starts automatically when you load the webpage and cycles through the 4 photos. But I want the slideshow to disappear (to reveal the website homepage underneath) after it has cycled through the 4 photos only once, but need some help how to proceed forward.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img id="pic" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Icon" src="one.jpg">
  </div>

  <script>
    var i, imgs, pic;

    function rotate() {
      pic.src = imgs[i];

      (i === (imgs.length - 1)) ? (i = 0) : (i++);
      setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
    }


    function init() {
      pic = document.getElementById("pic");

      imgs = ["one.jpg", "two.jpg", "three.jpg", "four.jpg"];

      var preload = new Array();
      for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        preload[i] = new Image();
        preload[i].src = imgs[i];
      }

      i = 0;
      rotate();
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var count = 0
function rotate() {
  pic.src = imgs[i];

  (i === (imgs.length - 1)) ? (i = 0) : (i++);
  if (count < imgs.length) {
    count++;
    setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
  } else {
  document.getElementById("slideshow").style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

Hi,
you have to count your number of slides. Afterwards just check if you already finished.

greetings

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img id="pic" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Icon" src="one.jpg">
  </div>

  <script>
    var i, imgs, pic;

    function rotate() {
      pic.src = imgs[i];
      if(i<(imgs.length - 1)){
       i++;
       setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
      }
      
    }


    function init() {
      pic = document.getElementById("pic");

      imgs = ["one.jpg", "two.jpg", "three.jpg", "four.jpg"];

      var preload = new Array();
      for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        preload[i] = new Image();
        preload[i].src = imgs[i];
      }

      i = 0;
      rotate();
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
if(i<(imgs.length - 1)){
   i++;
   setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
}
```

You need to check for how many time the `rotate()` method need to call.

Comment: Thanks alot for your input.